# Keyboard with SearchBar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using SearchBar class in Xamarin Forms
The problem is when I focus on the searchBar text box the Keyboard shown like in the following image,
It splits the screen vertically into two sections one for the view and the other for the keyboard, however, what i would like to achieve is the view should remain in the same height meanly occupy the whole screen height and the keyboard should overlap the view without compressing it.
Any help?

Note: when I focus on any other text box the keyboard works as expected, meanly the problem is only with the search bar text box.

[image]

Comment: Are your other text boxes `Editor`s ? I cannot reproduce your issue, their behaviors seems to be the same by my side. Could you please provide more details about your issue? Maybe the code of your layout? And your emulator info?

Comment: It is hard to share the code because of a couple of reasons the first one is it is complex the second one our company privacy.
this issue shown in every emulator and real devices so, I think the reason behind this issue is not the emulator, however, this is an visual studio android emulator,
10.1 KitKat (4.4) XHDPI Tablet API level 19 KitKat Similar to Samsung Google Nexus 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the following code OnCreate method on MainActivity class On android project:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
        window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this either with a sample app, but the issue seems related to the [SoftInputMode](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.WindowSoftInputMode/). By default Forms uses `AdjustPan` however when you focus on the SearchBar it sounds like it's using the `AdjustResize` behavior.

You can try using the new Platform Specifics feature in Forms 2.3.3 to see if it forces the SearchBar to use `AdjustPan`. With it you can [set the Android input mode](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/platform-specifics/consuming/#Setting_the_Soft_Keyboard_Input_Mode) on an application or page level.

Comment: I have tried to set the Android input mode [explained in this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/platform-specifics/consuming/#Setting_the_Soft_Keyboard_Input_Mode),
but I have got an error, however, your solution has guided me in the right direction so I have written the following code on OnCreate Method on anadroid project which solves the problem perfectly
            'var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
            window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);'